# Appcelerator studio cannot be launched "An error occurred"

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to launch Appcelerator Studio but I get this error "An error occurred" with this log file: [Log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruf0m0zm5j4ippy/1522616148749.log?dl=0)
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You're using Java version 9.0.4 which is not yet supported with the appcelerator studio 5.0.0 or earlier versions.

Please make sure you're using Java 1.8.131

Here is the direct link for JDK 1.8.131 - https://s3.amazonaws.com/titanium-studio/jdk/jdk-8u131-macosx-x64.dmg

If you think you also need JDK 1.8.152/153/JDK 9 on your system to support other applications. Here is my suggestion without uninstalling the existing JDK's.

Make sure you're having JDK 1.8.131 on your system. Check this

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_1131.jdk

Open **Appcelerator Studio.ini** file which you can find here

```
/Applications/Appcelerator\ Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/AppceleratorStudio.ini
```

Add below VM argument before the **-vmargs** and restart the studio. This will force the studio to use jdk1.8.0_131.jdk

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Here is the complete file content look like

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Dtitanium.moduleListUrl=http://preview.appcelerator.com/360/modules.json
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/titanium.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Reference:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8878

Comment: I added an older version of Java and now is working fine.

Comment: For me the location of AppceleratorStudio.ini is in /Applications/Appcelerator\ Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/AppceleratorStudio.ini

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to setup Appcelerator Studio is, only download studio dmg file if you are using mac or else exe if you are using windows. Then try to install, it will automatically ask to download the prerequisite, which is required i.e. jdk, node and titanium sdk. I hope it will help you.

Comment: really? what happens of you have java installed before?

Comment: remove that installed java from path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ and then try to install appcelerator.dmg

Comment: @CristiCalacianu, if you find this answer useful, mark it as answered then.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is logout using the console (before run Studio).